# HTTP network trace to cURL

Tags: curl, tcpdump, tshark

I am looking for a way to convert automatically a HTTP captured frame from [TCPdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html), or [Tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) into a [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) query.

For example, after dumping network traffic as a .pcap file, I would like to find a tool to convert HTTP GET, POST and PUT into cURL commands:
This is pretty much what [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) allows me to do
[image]

At the moment I am dissecting those HTTP frames from a .pcap file using Tshark, and save them into a database, then craft cURL queries in PHP but I occasionally experience issues while injecting POST data with different Content-Types (*multipart/form-data; boundary* for instance).

Would anyone know a tool or script to craft a cURL query from a pcap file or Tshark ?

Comment: Not aware of any. Make one!

Answer (score 0):

This was answer already:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46726868/4089733)

This is not perfect an needs tuning but if your request are simple. it should work just fine for you.