# Transfer a wireshark captured http request to a curl request

Tags: curl, wireshark

I am trying to simulate a post request from a system I am not familiar with(http thrift).

With wire shark, I get the http request like :[image].

But I am going to perform a stress test with tools like `ab`, so How I can transfer a Wireshark package to a `ab` or `curl` command http request ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here are two tools that can help you:

1. [h2c](https://curl.se/h2c/), HTTP headers to curl, which converts a HTTP request to a suitable curl command line. (written by me)
2. [pcap2curl](https://github.com/jullrich/pcap2curl), which is similar in style but instead converts a saved PCAP file with a HTTP request to a curl command line.

Comment: I like answer # 2.

Comment: I don't. No idea how to get "a saved PCAP file" from Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `tcptrace`.

For details, see: [Capture, save and resend requests with Wireshark](https://www.razorcodes.com/2018/02/12/capture_save_and_resend_requests_with_Wireshark.html)